# Looping through a table in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, indexing, import-from-csv

I am attempting to write a program in **R** which creates a table from a .csv file that will be 1856 x 9 items. This part works. Then, I would like to loop through each cell of that table, starting at the upper right hand corner of the table, and go backwards down a row, then drop down to the next row and do the same.

If the row is all zeros, or has `1 1 1 0 0 0`, or something similar, I want to delete it. If the row has all non zero values and then zero values to the right, delete it

If there exists a non-zero value in a cell to the right of a cell with a zero value, I want to keep the row in the table.

Example:

[image: Beginning of my table]

After my code runs, I want only rows 1, 2, 3, 7 to remain.

Comment: why would you ditch row 1 ? I don't understand your condition "has 1 1 1 0 0 0, or something similar"

Comment: could you state the conditions in clearer terms.  "something similar" is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Yes I just edited the main post. Basically, if there is a cell in the row which is a nonzero value, and there is a zero value to the left of it, I want to keep it. Everything else should be deleted. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: But row 1 has a nonzero value (Series.A) and a zero value (Seed) to the left of it, but you're not keeping that.

Comment: Im sorry I messed up. I do want to keep row 1. I apologize again I should have read through what I wrote another time.

Comment: Then you don't have any example of row you want to remove, that wouldn't be just zeroes :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper you are correct, no such instance occurs in the first 7 rows

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply instead of a loop :

```
# recreate your example
DF <- 
read.csv(
text="Company.Name,Seed,Series.A,Series.B,Series.C,Series.D,Series.E,Series.F,Series.G,Series.H
Aetion,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Aspier Healt,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Evariant,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0
iHealth,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Inuition Robotics,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kali Care,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Network Locum,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
"
)

# This line does :
# - for each row of DF excluding the first column DF[,-1]
# - take the row without the last value x[-length(x)] and the 
#   row without the first value x[-1]
# - create a vector with TRUE where x[-length(x)] == 0 AND x[-1] != 0
#   so basically when a zero is followed by a non-zero
# - if there's "any" (see the function) TRUE, then the condition is met
# rowCondition will contain TRUE where the row condition is met, and FALSE otherwise
rowCondition <- apply(DF[,-1],1,function(x) any(x[-length(x)] == 0 & x[-1] != 0))

# we use the condition to filter the necessary rows
subsetDF <- DF[rowCondition,]



> subsetDF
   Company.Name Seed Series.A Series.B Series.C Series.D Series.E Series.F Series.G Series.H
1        Aetion    0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2  Aspier Healt    1        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
3      Evariant    0        1        1        2        0        0        0        0        0
7 Network Locum    0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

Comment: What is X? Also, why does that show iHealth but not Intuition Robotics?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I put margin paramenter =2 in apply, instead of 1. Now is correct. About "x", is simply the argument of the function passed to apply, so it contains each row of the data.frame excluding the first column

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for any row where there is a 0 followed by a non-zero character it's possible to do this using regex. The `grepl` function returns a TRUE/FALSE vector based on whether the `pattern` specified is matched:

```
examples <- c("100", "000", "001")
grepl(pattern = "0[1-9]", x = examples)
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

This regex explicitly looks for a digit 1-9 following a zero, it you wanted ANY possible character other than a zero you would use `pattern = "0[^0]"`

Using the `dplyr` library, which is loaded by calling `library("tidyverse")` it's very simple to concatenate the columns of interest and then apply our regex to this new column.

First, save the following as a .csv

Company.Name,Seed,Series.A,Series.B,Series.C,Series.D,Series.E,Series.F,Series.G,Series.H
Aetion,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Aspier Healt,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Evariant,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0
iHealth,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Inuition Robotics,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Kali Care,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Network Locum,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Martin Company, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
Other Company, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9
Weird Company, 0, 0, 0, 0, m, 0, 0, 0, 0

Then import the data using read_csv:

```
library("tidyverse")
example_data <- read_csv("example_data.csv")
```

Now let's create a new column containing the concatenation of the rows Seed:Series.H

```
example_data <- example_data %>%
  mutate(test_col = paste0(Seed,
                           Series.A,
                           Series.B,
                           Series.C,
                           Series.D,
                           Series.E,
                           Series.F,
                           Series.G,
                           Series.H))
```

Let's have a look at the new column value for the first row:

```
example_data %>%
  select(test_col) %>%
  slice(1)
## 010000000
```

Okay! So there is a non-zero character to the right of a zero! So this row should be included in the output.

We can use the `mutate` verb to apply the `grepl` test across all rows in a new column called include. Let's print out the entire of this column to see which rows match your condition:

```
example_data %>%
    mutate(include = grepl("0[1-9]", test_col)) %>%
    select(include)
## output
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   include
     <lgl>
 1    TRUE
 2    TRUE
 3    TRUE
 4   FALSE
 5   FALSE
 6   FALSE
 7    TRUE
 8    TRUE
 9   FALSE
10   FALSE
```

To filter out only those rows where the condition is true we use the `filter` verb:

```
example_data %>%
  mutate(include = grepl("0[1-9]", test_col)) %>%
  filter(include)
```

Of course, we now have two columns in your data you don't want! So let's write all of this concisely:

```
example_data %>%
  mutate(test_col = paste0(Seed,
                           Series.A,
                           Series.B,
                           Series.C,
                           Series.D,
                           Series.E,
                           Series.F,
                           Series.G,
                           Series.H),
         include = grepl("0[1-9]", test_col)) %>%
  filter(include) %>%
  select(-include, -test_col)
```

Comment: Can you try it without regex? I really don't understand it.

Comment: @Mason hope the expanded explanation helps